# 64 bit executable won't run on 64 bit server

Tags: server, 64-bit, executable

The file:

```
root@hx:~/rippled/build# file rippled
rippled: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked (uses     shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0xb1afb32e01966d513ad400578185e1bea06fefb9, not stripped
```

The OS:

```
root@hx:~/rippled/build# uname -a
Linux hx 3.13.0-32-generic #57~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:20 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And yet:

```
root@hx:~/rippled/build# rippled
rippled: command not found
```

My question: What am I doing wrong? How can I get this to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a command in the current folder you are in you must preface the command with `./` where the `.` means "this folder" and the `/` means "going into".  So, in the terminal in the `rippled/build` folder you would type `./rippled` to run the program.  The `./` can be thought of as "current folder."  Other commands run without this specific syntax because they are in your system "path" and your build folder isn't.

Comment: +1 probably correct --- normally Unix does not include the current directory (`.`) in the path, to avoid mistakes... especially if you are root.